# Having problem in Greating QrCodes in bulk and saving them with custom layout

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm trying to bulk generate and save Qrcodes with custom layouts from a data base.

The loop I created works, it saves in bulk. But the problem is when saving in bulk, Information that should be fetched from database and displayed are not showing up, **only** qrcode shows up. But if I save Manually one by one, All information shows up.

[Saving manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dqxYB.jpg)
[Saving in bulk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/boTeQ.png)

Code For saving layout:

```java
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
public void screen(String name) {
    try {
        CardView content = findViewById(R.id.massgenrate);
        content.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        Bitmap bitmap = content.getDrawingCache();
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy_MM_dd_hh_mm_ss");
        Date now = new Date();
        String fileName = formatter.format(now);

        File file, f;

        if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)) {
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "DCIM");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.mkdirs();
            }
            f = new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + file.separator + name + fileName + ".png");

            FileOutputStream ostream = new FileOutputStream(f);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 10, ostream);
            Toast.makeText(this, "done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            ostream.close();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Code For loop:

```java
public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {

        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            userinfo dbb = snapshot.getValue(userinfo.class);
// sets Text for textviews
            name.setText(dbb.getFirstname() + " " + dbb.getLastname());
            work.setText(dbb.getWorkplace());
            occu.setText(dbb.getOccupation());
// email garbed from the db is sent to qrGenrator tp create the code. 
            qrGenrator(dbb.getEmail());
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            creating.setText(" ");
//sends firstname to screen function which saves the file with persons firstname
            screen(dbb.getFirstname);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think we have enough information to be able to help fully. What exactly do you mean by "save manually". It would be great if you could show is some more code with a more complete example on what's going on. My first guess would be that your dbb get methods are returning null and you should get on there with a debugger and see why it's null when you expect it not to be.

Comment: By saving manually I mean , there is button on the layout page that is using the same screen() function from the loop. If I click that to save, the fetched information saves just like I want it to i.e name, occupation, work and Qrcode.  But i have a lot of data, so i cant do it one by one.  That's why i implemented the loop. when i run the loop, it is generating and saving all the data in my db but only QR code is showing. eg if there is data from 5 people, it will generate 5 different .png with correct Qrcode. but other fields are empty.

Comment: and im sure the loop is not returning null because the qrcode generated is correct. the information fetched from the db in the loop is used to generate the QRCode. If loop was returning null, the qrcode would also had been wrong